# JS/Html: Editable-Textarea without underline

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

In my html code I have a editable-textarea like this:

```
<span editable-textarea="category.name">{{category.name}}</span>
```

By default the text has now a dotted underline. I don't want the dotted underline but I don't get it away. I tried it with the following stylings:

```
<span editable-textarea="category.name" style="text-decoration: none; text-underline: none">{{category.name}}</span>
```

But even text-decoration or text-underline get it away. Some other solutions?

P.S. category.name is saved in my js data. I think its not important in here. Can be every text.

Comment: what is "editable-textarea"?  I have never seen that in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change border-bottom

Add this style:

```
border-bottom: none;
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/15503/) you have a working fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you -

js code

```
document.getElementById("editable-span").spellcheck = false;
```

html

```
<span id="editable-span" editable-textarea="category.name">{{category.name}}</span>
```

the dotted line appears may be due to spell check.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way

```
<span editable-textarea="category.name" style="border:none;">{{category.name}}</span>
```